# How do I exit if there is no new output within a defined timeframe

Tags: node.js

I'm running a NodeJS server, which becomes hung due to various factors. Every time this happens, I have to restart the NodeJS server to resolve the issue. Is there any workaround that exits the process automatically if there is no output within a defined timeframe? I suppose setTimeout() and the "process" module are needed, however, I'm unaware of how to achieve it elegantly.

Comment: I would work at fixing why it is being hung before constantly restarting the server.

Comment: By doing this you'll break whatever node is currently achieving. Try to find out why it's breaking before hacking around!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would exit a process after a timespan with `setTimeout()`. Its worth noting though you should just resolve your error in  your process first though.

```
var input; // your input
var timeout = 60000; // timeout amount
setTimeout(timeout, function() {

  if (!input)
    process.exit(1);

});
```

The `process` module and `setTimeout()`are globals, they're automatically available to your module from the Node.js Core API.

---

#### Edit- ChildProcess

Since your "hanging" based on this TCP Module, take your implementing module and run it using [`childProcess.fork()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/v4.4.0/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options). Then you can react to the lack of output from the module and kill the process accordingly.

Create a new file and put the following in it

```
var process = require('child_process');

// Spawn your Hanging Code
var tcp = process.fork('<pathToYourTcpCode>');
var timeout = 60000; // timeout amount

var output = '';

tcp.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  output += data;
});

setTimeout(timeout, function() {
  if (!output)
    tcp.kill('SIGINT');
});
```

Comment: This won't work if the server is actually "hung" and not running Javascript any more.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes thats true but if its just waiting on output from an I/O callback that's never being called and not actually "hung" this will do the trick. This scenario is how I read the question.

Comment: To decouple this hack with the code, which is a bit complex, is it possible that we get the console output ourselves?

Comment: Why not use `console.log()` within the code thats executing to see where its "hanging" and then debug from there?

Comment: @peteb I think it's a TCP connection. Yet because I use a third-party module, it's hard for me to intervene it.

Comment: @IsilmëO. Checkout my updated answer, I think you can do better using a `ChildProcess` and then controlling it from a different node process that can kill your TCP module if it hangs.

Comment: @IsilmëO. If a package is causing your entire server to hang or become unresponsive I would consider ditching that package.